# Application initialization fails because one jar file is accessing properties files contained in another jar

Tags: java, spring, jar

I have a Spring Application which uses Quartz Scheduler library. 
The Quartz jar file contains a `build.properties` file which `QuartzScheduler` class accesses during initialization to read the version number.

After adding another unrelated jar to the project, QuartzScheduler started throwing exception at time of initialization. I found that this new jar also had a file called `build.properties`. Moreover, it also has the `version` property that `QuartzScheduler` class looks for.

The version number format of the two jars is different and the string splitting logic fails which generates the exception.

How do I make the offending class access `build.properties` file from its own jar.

Both jars are from third parties and I preferably do not want to modify them.

Comment: Put the build.properties file in another place of classpath and modify the QuartzScheduler source to read your point.

Comment: @pmverma But that involves modifying the JAR which I preferably don't want to. I have already deleted build.properties from one JAR to make the APP run but this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: I do not mean to modify the jar, but copy the original build.properties and put in your desire classpath, get the source of QuartzScheduler and modify only the part of the code which read build.properties. And place your compiled class file in the correct package. This will read your build.propeties.

Comment: You have deleted the build.properties from one jar, this also is another "work is going" way. :)